# Change namespace for entire project in VS 2017

Tags: c#, namespaces, refactoring, visual-studio-2017

Previously some of the classes were present in `MyProject.Web.Core` project, which are moved to `MyProject.Model` project. However these moved classes have namespace as `MyProject.Web.Core`.

So, how can I change the namespace for all classes to `MyProject.Model` as we don't want to update them manually. Is there any option available in VS2017 ?

We have already update the default namespace in project properties, so that will be get applied when new class is added. But, how about for the moved/old classes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set your cursor into the namespace and then hit <kbd>F2</kbd> to rename (if <kbd>F2</kbd> didn't work, try <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> or rightclick - rename). All related namespaces should be changed.

Comment: What does STRG means ?

Comment: Does this rename in the current project OR in the entire solution where that namespace is been referred ? As it is showing me more number of files will get changed rather than what I expected !

Comment: Its changed in the entire solution. If you want these changes only happen in your project, you could copy out the project, do the rename changes and copy it back.  Opening only the project instead of the solution could help maybe too.

Comment: This doesn't work if you place the item into a sub folder and want to append ".foldername" to the namespace.

Comment: You will also have to rename (Ctrl +Shift + H) all files not ending with .cs; for instance CSHTML files. Just do a global search and replace.

Answer (score 4):

This is a case where [Jetbrains Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) can help you. It identifies namespace mismatches and allows fixing it solution-wide.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help !